# The debugger cannot connect to the remote computer. The debugger was unable to resolve the specified computer name

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I am trying to run a project in a solution in debug mode, but I get an error.

> The debugger cannot connect to the remote computer. The debugger was unable to resolve the specified computer name.

I am able to run localhost and I created a new project and the debuggers runs. I get the error when I try to run a project that is a website in a solution.

Comment: You probably should check your IIS settings and/or wwwRoot to see what your configurations are.

Comment: I have the same exact settings as my co-workers and my co-worker is able to compile and run the project in debug mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your localhost works maybe modifying your hosts file will resolve the issue. Not sure why the URL needs to be configured to something specific.  However, in your hosts file you can configure your URL to say whatever you'd like.

hosts file is located, C:/Windows/System32/drivers/etc/hosts  on Windows10.  You may have to search if different OS.  I hope this helps.

In your hosts file change where it says:
127.0.0.1 localhost
to
127.0.0.1 test.local

Comment: I ended up doing what you answered. In IIS I had four non virtual websites all pointing to localhost port 80. I added each website to the host file. So, your answer is the correct answer.

Comment: Thanks can you up tick it if you get a chance.  Looks like it was auto answered anyways but would help someone down the road knowing that it worked.  Good luck to you.

Answer (score 0):

I had this message in VS because I forgot that the last time I've used that project I was attaching to a remote machine.
So in the properties of the project I've set the flag "Use remote machine" with the name of the machine.
And VS was telling me that was not able to resolve the specified computer name, but I didn't beleive it..

[image]

If that is your case, removing the flag should work.